# How the default website in VWD 2010 works?

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2010

Ok, this might sound as a silly question, but I am a newbie without experience, and I am curious how stuff works, I am not for the "just works".

The default website generated by VWD2010 is documented somewhere? I searched in MSDN but no luck.

If i understand how it works, it would be better, to understand how login is implemented, the master page, and so on.

Comment: Please tell us which "default website" you're asking about. Also please give more detail about what you want to know. "how does it work" is a very broad question.

Comment: ok, i explain better.
In VWD 20005 and 2008, if you create an empty website, will be only created an empty default.aspx + web.config. In 2010 it creates a cool template with login pages, master pages, css and jquery. I need instruction of how this works. I used to create small independent pages with simple functions, I never did a complete website.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like you're looking for tutorials. I suggest [Microsoft's free tutorials](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/aa336522.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

When you create a new website, the IDE creates that website using a template.  The template has code for the website.  For example, creating a .css file and linking that.  Look through the files that are generated and look at the code that is there.

I suggest you start here at the [Get Started page](http://www.asp.net/get-started) for ASP.NET.